# Search box floats down in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I am using a Wordpress-based theme for my site. When I use the search box that comes with the theme, everything works fine. But when I use Google Search box, it floats down. You can see the site here: http://www.shoutpedia.com

I tried different options but none of them worked.

There is no push down in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE9.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might fix this?

Comment: You should edit question to include some of the options that you've already tried but didn't work. That way, we don't have to start over from the beginning suggesting things that you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your ul.nav class is pushing full width. You have a ul.nav css style set to display:inline-block. Try removing that.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of IE7 rendering when you remove that style. In the screenshot you can see the rendering and also the style that I unchecked. Hope this helps. http://bobcravens.com/demos/test/photo1.png